# OOP implementation of BlackJack in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, playing-cards

This code is not done, but still fully functional.

But, before I continue I'd really appreciate some input on the code-structure as is.

**AbstractHand.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public abstract class AbstractHand<T extends Suitable & Rankable> {
    protected List<T> hand = new ArrayList<>();

    public void drawCard(T o) {
        hand.add(o);
    }

    public void drawCards(T[] o) {
        hand.addAll(Arrays.asList(o));
    }

    public abstract void status();
    public abstract int calculateScore();
}
```

**Deck.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Deck<T extends Suitable & Rankable> {
    T dealCard();
    T[] dealCards(int n);
    void shuffle();
}
```

**Rankable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Rankable<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    boolean isConsecutive(T other);
}
```

**Suitable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Suitable<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    boolean isSameSuit(T other);
}
```

**Card.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;

import com.tn.deck.Rankable;
import com.tn.deck.Suitable;



public class Card implements Suitable<Card>, Rankable<Card>, Comparable<Card> {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Rank rank;

    Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("%s%s ", suit.getIcon(), rank.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConsecutive(Card other) {
        return 1 + rank.ordinal() == other.rank.ordinal() ||
                rank.ordinal() - 1 == other.rank.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSameSuit(Card other) {
        return suit.equals(other.suit);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        if(rank.getValue() == other.getRank().getValue() &&
                suit.getIcon().equals(other.getSuit().getIcon())) {
            return 0;
        } else if(rank.getValue() < other.getRank().getValue()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**CardDeck.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;

import com.tn.deck.Deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class CardDeck implements Deck<Card> {
    private static final Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    private List<Card> deck;
    private List<Card> dealtCards;

    CardDeck(Suit[] suits, Rank[] ranks) {
        this.deck = initializeDeckWith(suits, ranks);
        this.dealtCards = new ArrayList<>();
        shuffle();
    }

    private List<Card> initializeDeckWith(Suit[] suits, Rank[] ranks) {
        List<Card> newDeck = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Suit suit : suits) {
            for(Rank rank : ranks) {
                newDeck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
            }
        }
        return newDeck;
    }

    @Override
    public Card dealCard() {
        if(deck.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Deck is empty");
        }
        int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
        Card card = deck.get(rand.nextInt(index));
        deck.remove(index);
        dealtCards.add(card);

        return card;
    }

    @Override
    public Card[] dealCards(int n) {
        if(deck.size() < n) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not enough cards left in deck");
        }

        Card[] cardsToDeal = new Card[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
            Card card = deck.get(index);
            deck.remove(index);
            cardsToDeal[i] = card;
            dealtCards.add(card);
        }
        return cardsToDeal;
    }

    @Override
    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }
}
```

**Dealer.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;

import com.tn.deck.AbstractHand;


public class Dealer extends AbstractHand<Card> {
    private CardDeck deck;

    Dealer() {
        this.deck = new CardDeck(Suit.getSuits(), Rank.getRanks());
    }

    public void startInitialDealingOfCards(Player[] players) {
        for(Player player : players) {
            Card[] initialCards = deck.dealCards(2);
            player.drawCards(initialCards);
        }
        Card[] dealersInitialCards = deck.dealCards(2);
        drawCards(dealersInitialCards);
    }

    @Override
    public void status() {
        System.out.printf("%nThe Dealer, has the following hand:%n");
        hand.forEach(Card::print);
        System.out.printf("( score of %d )", calculateScore());
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateScore() {
        return hand.stream().mapToInt(card -> card.getRank().getValue()).sum();
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;

import com.tn.deck.AbstractHand;


public class Player extends AbstractHand<Card> {
    private int id;

    Player(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void status() {
        System.out.printf("%nPlayer %d, has the following hand:%n", id);
        hand.forEach(Card::print);
        System.out.printf("( score of %d )", calculateScore());
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateScore() {
        return hand.stream().mapToInt(card -> card.getRank().getValue()).sum();
    }
}
```

**Rank.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;


public enum Rank {
    TWO("2", 2), THREE("3", 3), FOUR("4", 4), FIVE("5", 5),
    SIX("6", 6), SEVEN("7", 7), EIGHT("8", 8), NINE("9", 9), TEN("10", 10),
    JACK("J", 10), QUEEN("Q", 10), KING("K", 10), ACE("A", 11);

    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    Rank(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Rank[] getRanks() {
        return new Rank[] {
                TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE,
                SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN,
                JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
        };
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Suit.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;


public enum Suit {
    SPADE("\u2660"),
    HEART("\u2665"),
    DIAMOND("\u2666"),
    CLUB("\u2663");

    private final String icon;

    Suit(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public static Suit[] getSuits() {
        return new Suit[] { SPADE, HEART, DIAMOND, CLUB };
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
package com.tn.blackjack;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Game {
    private Dealer dealer;
    private Player[] players;

    public Game() {
        this.dealer = new Dealer();
        this.players = new Player[] {
                new Player(1),
                new Player(2)
        };
    }

    public void start() {
        dealer.startInitialDealingOfCards(players);
        dealer.status();
        Arrays.stream(players).forEach(Player::status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents

#### Abstraction / inherticance

I always try to avoid abstraction and inheritance. In general, it's really hard, to achieve a high cohesion when working with abstraction, because it's very tempting to mix abstraction and implementation. Beside that, it's not possible to (unit) test abstraction *without* implementation, the other way round, often you will test abstraction/logic from the super class implicitly when testing implementation. Also: The more inheritance is present, the more complex it gets - if you pass another parameter in the constructor in the base class, have fun changing all your subclasses. Some subclasses override methods, some don't, some call abstract methods, some don't.

A very confusing part of your code is: A Player *is a* hand. The Dealer *is a* hand. They both should *have a* Hand, don't they?

#### overcomplicating things

I don't see any need for your interfaces, for instances the `Rankable` and `Suitable` interfaces - nowhere in the code you declare anything as one of those types. If anyone teached you, to make your application "future proof", by this sort of "over-engineering", don't listen to him: in most of the cases, it's not needed. I used to do that, too, but I just ended up with way too much unnecessary and harder to maintain code. Or sometimes even worse, what I thought, what will help in the future, had to be dismantled, because, well, I ain't no fortune teller and the requirements went the complete opposite way.

#### separation of concerns

A class should do one thing, also called single responsibility principle. Your `Dealer` class is a `Hand`, does calculate the score, prints the status and does some initialization. Since a Dealer should not be a Hand anyway and should be a state of the Dealer, some responsibilites will be moved to the correct place.

Printing/displaying objects is something I see often at the wrong place. Objects shouldn't display itself, there should be a separate type which does that job.

#### Other things

Noone seems to call `isSameSuit`? I only find it in the interface and in the implementation. And I think there's other unused methods, too. The IDE should usually show unused code, if not, try to figure out how to activate that. Dead code is something like a deadly sin.

Also: Sometimes you work with arrays, sometimes with Lists, I think you don't need to work with arrays.

Abstract Hand

- The name `drawCard` is incorrect. You add a card, the drawing happens somewhere else, same for drawCards.
- `status()` - Status what? What should one do when he overrides that method? I mentioned, the displaying of a type should be in a separate type anyway - but `printStatus` would be more precise. Or even better: `printHand()`, since status could mean anything. Try to be a specific as possible.

Deck

The dealCards has a parameter `n`. It's not clear, what n means, better would have been `amountOfCards`.

Card.compareTo

- I think there's a bug in the compareTo method, you only compare the value when the suit is the same. If the value is the same, but not the suit, you will return 1, won't you?
- You can write that much easier, I wouldn't have even implemented the first if condition, only < and >, then it's 0 in the end anyway. I would also get rid of the first else if, if the first condition is met, the method will return, if not, it will get into the else-if anyway, so one if on a separate line is enough.

CardDeck

- You can initialize your variables in the class, so the constructor is easier to read.
- `initializeDeckWith`: I think, the "with" suffix is obsolete. It doesn't really help and the parameters should make it clear enough.
- `dealCard` / `dealCards`: You have duplication here (DRY: "don't repeat yourself"), just call the dealCard from dealCards. Except the guard, that should stay. Also: The `remove` method does return the removed object, so no need to get the object at the specific index and remove it aftwards. Also: If you provide a shuffle method for a deck, I don't think a `Random` is needed.

Dealer

`startInitialDealingOfCards`: The method name is not clear, I had to read the method to be sure, what's going on: It deals the first two cards. Maybe `dealInitialTwoCards`. Even though, many are familiar with the Black Jack rules, not all are.

Rank / Suit

I don't understand, why you are providing separate methods to get the values, enum's already provide those methods. I wouldn't suggest to do that, because that's your own convention. If it doesn't do what the default method for an enum does, give it a proper name.

Hope that helps...

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you.  I agree the abstract class is badly named. I've renamed it to AbstractPlayer instead.

Comment: changed the abstract stuff a little bit, and would like your opinion on it. You can find it here. https://github.com/Nilzone-/Blackjack

Comment: You seem to have missed slowy's point about Players **holding** a hand instead of **being** a hand. A player should have a variable `AbstractHand hand` instead of extending `AbstractHand`

Comment: @Imus: That's what I meant :-)

Comment: I have read through this a couple of times now. Would you mind showing with (through code) the abstractHand as composition as opposed to inheritance, and how a class the is responsible for printing objects would look like?

Answer (score 2):

Overall your code looks pretty good. Nice formatting, nice split of responsibilities (so far), ...

There's only 1 thing that bothers me with your interfaces. And that's the **YAGNI** principle. That's short for "You Aren't Going to Need It".

Since you're modelling a game of blackjack, you're never really going to need to compare suits, so why provide an interface to do so?

Same for the `Rankable` interface. When would you need this in a blackjack game?

It's usually best to not write code that you don't expect to need any time soon. It will just distract you from doing the actual requirements.

---

Another thing that might be tricky later is the value of an ACE. It could actually be 11 or 1 depending on the total value of your hand. Not that your enum is wrong, but remember that you might have to substract 10 at some point. Alternatively you could give it value 1 in the enum and add 10 when the total hand value is less than 12.

---

The last thing I want to point out is that the `calculateScore` should be the same for a dealer or a normal player. So you should implement it in the abstract class and drop the `abstract` keyword. That way you Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY principle).

---

edit: Just remembered the [hidden enum functions](http://programming.guide/java/javadoc-for-enum-values.html). Instead of providing `public static Suit[] getSuits() {` you could just call `Suit.values()` which gives you the exact same result. Same for the `public static Rank[] getRanks() {` method.

If you want to keep them for better readability you could also just change their implemenation to this:

```
public static Rank[] getRanks() {
    return Rank.values();
}
```

Comment: All valid points - thank you! I already thought about the calculateScore - and how it should be implemented in the abstract class since they are the same, but how? How can I access rank to get the values when I just have a List<T>?

Comment: Why don't you turn that class into an `AbstractHand<Card>` instead? Note, you should just drop the type altogether and replace it with `Card` inside the abstract class. A lot cleaner :)

Comment: You're probably right. I'm new to generics and got a bit caught up in it :)

Comment: You did understand how to make a class generic, but it's not really useful in this specific case. Same for the `Deck` class. In practice, you're always going to talk about "a deck of cards", not "a deck of things with suits and numbers". So in this specific case, you're better of dropping the `T` altogether.

Comment: I agree - Although I don't want to drop generics all together because I want to be able to reuse most of the deck-package for other card-games as well. For the calculatedScore method for example; Would it be reasonable to Make a BlackjackHand class that extends AbstractHand where I could override that method, and then have the Dealer and Player extend that class instead?

Comment: Like @slowy already pointed out in his answer: A Dealer and Player shouldn't extend any Hand. They **have** a hand, they **are not** hands themselves. Having a BlackjackHand that extends Abstracthand might work depending on what exactly you do with it. A player should have a field `AbstractHand` without knowing if it's a blackjackhand or a pokerhand. It just HAS a hand.

Comment: Dropping the generics shouldn't mean making it less reusable. It's just that it's always `Card`s you're talking about. No matter what game you play. So you don't need a generic type to generalise things. If you can't reuse anything you should restructure the code better. (For example, using more composition instead of inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

No big problems... just some small pointers. :)

#### Varargs

```
public void drawCard(T o) {
    hand.add(o);
}

public void drawCards(T[] o) {
    hand.addAll(Arrays.asList(o));
}
```

You can combine both methods with varags so that you can pass in one or multiple cards without having to make an array explicitly:

```
public void drawCards(T... cards) {
    hand.addAll(Arrays.asList(cards));
}

// Usage
// player.drawCards(oneCard);
// player.drawCards(oneCard, twoCard);
```

#### Checking for consecutiveness

A simpler check is to make sure that the absolute difference of the cards' values is 1:

```
@Override
public boolean isConsecutive(Card other) {
    return Math.abs(ordinal() - other.ordinal()) == 1;
}
```

#### `Enum` arrays

Your `Rank.getRanks()` and `Suit.getSuits()` can simply call the underlying `Enum.values()` method as the returned results will be the same.

#### Java 8 stream processing

In the spirit of Java 8, you can stream through your `Card` creation:

```
private List<Card> initializeDeckWith(Suit[] suits, Rank[] ranks) {
    List<Card> newDeck = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Suit suit : suits) {
        for(Rank rank : ranks) {
            newDeck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
        }
    }
    return newDeck;
}
```

Java 8 way:

```
private List<Card> initializeDeckWith(Suit[] suits, Rank[] ranks) {
    return Arrays.stream(suits)
                .flatMap(suit -> Arrays.stream(ranks)
                                        .map(rank -> new Card(suit, rank)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really liked the java 8 loop with map and flatMap! :) Should I be consistent and change all my loop to something like that - or is it more appropriate in some places and others not so much?

Comment: Consistency matters. :) Just take note that since lambdas doesn't play well with checked exceptions, that should be the only time when you will want to stick with plain old `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Bug: the method `dealCard` can never deal the last card of the deck because you call `rand.nextInt` twice. Plus, it favors cards from the beginning of the deck. This should also sometimes throw exceptions, since you then call `rand.nextInt(0)`, which would have to return a number between 0 (lower bound, inclusive) and 0 (upper bound, exclusive), and this is impossible.

A better way is to first create the deck, then shuffle the complete deck (`Collections.shuffle` does that for you) and then always deal the top card from the deck. Separating the shuffling from the dealing more closely models what happens in reality, plus you can better test the part that deals the cards.

Comment: I agree - I already have a shuffle method (which I'm using), so there is no need for a random-index. I can just grab the first N cards instead.